# How do I extract an interface from a library in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I a using the library puppeteer however I would only like to instantiate one browser. So I'm using a top level function to create the browser and passing it as a parameter to helper functions like so:

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
export async function scrape() {
    const browser = await puppeteer
        .launch({
            //product:'chrome',
            //executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        })
        .catch(() => {});
    scrapeVmb(browser)
    scrapeChase(browser)
}
```

The problem becomes that I lose the intelisense inside the helper functions for the pupeteer library, This problem could be solved by setting the type of the browser parameter, however I do not know where to find the type of browser.

**TLDR**
How can I get the browser parameter to inherit the browser type inside the "scrapeVmb" and "scrapeChase" functions.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with it some more (I don't understand HOW this works so if someone knows it might be worthy of an answer) you can do:

```
type browserType = puppeteer.Browser
```

That will give you the browser interface which you can then use like so:

```
function scrapeEtc(browser:browserType) {
  //...
{
```